# Trouble with plotting in a loop in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I apologize in advance for the lack of a concrete example here but I really do not know where my error is so I cannot reproduce it in a simplified example and the actual code is far too complicated to post.

I'm plotting in ggplot in a loop and upon each of my three iterations I store the plot object in a list that I later use to plot to a pdf.  The issue I'm having is that the only way to get the correct plot objects stored in my list is to print each plot object after it is saved.  If I do not perform this step, the plots are not correct. (The fill colors I set for geom_rects for the the 1st two times through the loop are somehow incorrectly set to the colors used for the last loop iteration.)  I'm pretty confused and cannot figure out how just plotting after saving makes everything work fine.

Sorry again about the non-concrete nature of this problem but any help is appreciated.

Comment: lazy evaluation, if you search a bit, you'll find other questions related to this

Comment: Without a concrete example, we can't provide a solution. But it sounds like you need to learn about promises and scoping rules in R with respect to non-standard evaluation of parameters in `ggplot`.